# I keep getting an error trying to create a new react app

Tags: reactjs, npm

has anyone ever come across this issue before, where I am trying to create a new React application and I am being told to uninstall globally?

I have tried uninstalling but it keeps giving the same response, I tried clearing cache using npm cache clear --ff but I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCOKa.png) keep getting "recommended protection disabled"

Comment: Do you have this requirements ? Node >= 14.0.0 and npm >= 5.6

Comment: npx normally does not install the library only executing it - it looks to me as if you installed the library and it wants you to keep from that. What kind of system do you run? On Unix based systems you can use NVM to manage multiple node instances so you can easily try this with an another node version.

Comment: Thanks for responding Janos, I use a Windows OS, it have tried doing npm uninstall -g create-react-app several, but even after doing this, when I run the command again, I still get the same response.